# Removing radio button and label from document flow with jQuery

Tags: jquery, radio-button, hide

I have a modal with some radio buttons. There are 6 total. However, based on certain conditions, not all the radio buttons are supposed to show. I am using .hide() to hide the radio buttons that should not show when a certain condition is met. When the radio button is hidden, then the element shows in DevTools that it has a style of "display: none" on it. The problem is that the missing radio button still leaves a gap in the document flow, i.e. a gap in the modal. I thought display: none meant that an item was not only hidden but was removed from the document flow.

Here is my code. I had to change all the names and such because it is an issue at work.

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div id="radioButtons">
  </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript (jQuery)

```
radioButtonsHTML = $(
  '<input name="mainList" type="radio" id="startPacket" value="STRTPCKT" /> <label 
id="startPacketLabelId" for="startPacket" style="padding-left:8px;">Start Packet<span id="startPacketIncludedLabelId" style="font-weight:normal"> (Request Includes All Items)</span></label><br>' +
'<input name="mainList" type="radio" id="confScheduleRadio" value="CONF_SCHEDULE" /> <label id="confSheduleRadioLabelId" for="confSheduleRadio" style="padding-left:8px;">Conference Schedule</label><br>' +
'<input name="mainList" type="radio" id="rulesRadio" value="RULES" /> <label id="rulesRadioLabelId" for="rulesRadio" style="padding-left:8px;">Rules<span id="rulesIncludedLabelId" style="font-weight:normal"> (Request Includes All Terms and Conditions)</span></label><br>' +
'<input name="mainList" type="radio" id="secondStartPacket" value="..." /> <label id="secondStartPacketLabelId" for="secondStartPacket" style="padding-left:8px;">Second Start Packet<span id="secondStartPacketIncludedLabelId" style="font-weight:normal"> (Request Includes All Items)</span></label><br>' +
'<input name="mainList" type="radio" id="secondConfScheduleRadio" value="..." /> <label id="secondConfScheduleLabelId" for="secondConfScheduleRadio" style="padding-left:8px;">Second Conference Schedule</label><br>' +
'<input name="mainList" type="radio" id="secondRulesRadio" value="..." /> <label id="secondRulesRadioLabelId" for="secondRulesRadio" style="padding-left:8px;">Second Set of Rules<span id="secondRulesIncludedLabelId" style="font-weight:normal"> (Request Includes All Terms and Conditions)</span></label>' +
"<br/> <br/>"
);

radioButtonsHTML.appendTo("#radioButtons");

$("input[id*=startPacket]:radio").hide();
$("[id*=startPacketLabelId]").hide();
$("input[id*=secondStartPacket]:radio").hide();
$("[id*=secondStartPacketLabelId]").hide();
```

The code may be found on my Codepen [here](https://codepen.io/dtarvin/pen/ExvjrMv).

For brevity's sake for this question, rather than include all the conditions and the various ways different elements get hidden, I just set two buttons and labels to hide without a condition. It gets the point across.

If I hid the last four lines of the code I posted (all the .hide() statements), the modal looks like this:
[image]

However, if I leave the .hide() statements in place, the modal looks like this:
[image]

Is there any way to get rid of the gaps when certain buttons are hidden? I assume they have to be taken out of the document flow, but how can I do that in this situation?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried fadeOut() and fadeIn()

Comment: That doesn't work either.

Comment: Upon thorough lookup of your code, your problem is with where you place  <br> tag which falls outside your target for hiding the inputs

Comment: I tried moving the <br> tag just inside the closing </label> tag. It worked on the codepen, but in the code for work it just made all of the items side by side.

Comment: I ended up removing the <br> tags and putting each line with the <input> and <label> in a <span> set to display: block. That got rid of the gap.